# OSX: PHP Error localhost and unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, localhost, startup, osx-mavericks

How can i fix this php error?

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

I am on a mac/mavericks and I have made a mistake and did a `sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini` so now I get the error stated above when I run `php -v`

Comment: that path suggests you're on a Unix system, but are trying to load a Windows .dll. Good luck getting that to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, I followed these step-by-step guides to set up apache, php, mysql, etc and and get my localhost working:

1. http://brianflove.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-and-apache/
2. http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/

Then, I accidentally replaced my php.ini file and got the error stated above in the question. Actually, at first I got the `mcrypt` missing error.

So, after fixing all of these, I had few things left to do in the php.ini file:

1. Declared mcrypt like this: `extension=mcrypt.so`
2. Uncommented the extension_dir line and added: 
   `extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/"`
3. I commented out the line: `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`
4. Done a `sudo apachectl restart`

Finally, everything works as is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this as it worked for me...

The error coming for me was:

```
$ sudo php -v
# PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/phalcon.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/phalcon.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
# PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
# Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
# Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Run this as root:

```
$ locate phalcon.so
# /opt/local/lib/php55/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/phalcon.so
```

Run this also as root:

```
$ cp -rp /opt/local/lib/php55/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/phalcon.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
```

Just edit the directories as they might differ for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I had this error there were no available answers to my question. So I included above the steps I did and fixed the problem. But anyway, this looks as another workaround!

Answer (score 0):

In the php.ini file, if you had a unique extensions folder as required in macOS Sierra, make sure the extensions directory read like:

```
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/mcrypt.so
```

It's easy to forget to add the first "/"

Comment: This issue was addressed when I was on Mavericks!

Comment: I've been having the same problem now. I'm trying to get a CodeIgniter project running.