# Doctrine cannot connect to database in Symfony2 using Mamp

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create database through doctrine.

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

When I run the command above, I receive the following errors:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

### What I have tried

This symbolic link creation did not work for me.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

I've tried with both
`database_host: localhost` and `database_host: 127.0.0.1` nothing changed.

I know that my MySQL port is `8889` as I can see on MAMP.

I could not check the option **Allow network access to MySQL** under MySQL tab on MAMP since I do not have **MAMP Pro**

### Here are my configuration files

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@FatihTestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    cache: false

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

parameters.yml:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: 8889
    database_name: todo
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: fgnfgmngfm
```

Comment: Have you verified the MySQL user/pass by running from the command line: `mysql -u root -p` and that you are able to login, and that the database `todo` has *already* been created?

Comment: after I tried to run this command `mysql -u root -p`, I received this `-bash: mysql: command not found`. Then I copied the file **/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql**  as **/usr/local/bin/mysql** then I ran the same command, I successfully logged in. `mysql> show databases` showed **todo** as output.

Comment: In my config, it has `database_port` set to `null`. I wonder if you can try that. I'm thinking it may know about the port already.

Comment: it did not help either. it was null at first anyway. I tried sth else. I went to php.ini, uncommented this line `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`. now I receive this error `Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.12_5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.12_5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
`

Comment: I presume you are running Symfony2; can you run `php app/check.php` from the command line to see if all requirements are met? I'm not certain this is related to the problem though - but it's good to check.

Comment: yes I am running Symfony2. Looks like there is no problem: http://prntscr.com/d33wa3

Comment: Can you also try `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to see what result you get with that?

Comment: This is what I get @AlvinBunk http://prntscr.com/d343wu

Comment: You might have to do some more searching, but [see if this post helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384764/osx-php-error-localhost-and-unable-to-load-dynamic-library). Maybe sure you get this working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

The problem was because of cache, I received error messages not matter what I did. The command above that clears the cache and
changing the database port to 3306 in both **MAMP** and **paramteters.yml** has solved the problem.

Comment: Wow, I gave you all those suggestions (without an upvote) and it turned out you used the default port and it works. Regardless, glad you got it working!

Comment: @Fatih Please don't forget to clear cache after changing config parameters of symfony application.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS settings. If you are not using a VPN, turn it off.

You can test the connection with "Sequel PRO"

Hostname : localhost - 127.0.0.1 - IP Adress

Password : 1234 - root

If they do not solve the problem check the user permissions. [image]

mysql database -> user table

Comment: What do you mean by "If you are not using a VPN, turn it off"?

Comment: VPN applications route all traffic and there may be a connection problem.

Comment: Well, what I don't understand is if I am not using a VPN, how can I possibly turn it off? I have a VPN configured but it is off. http://prntscr.com/d33xiu

Comment: Try changing the database port to MySQL by default. 3306

Comment: After I changed db port to 3306, the error message has changed to this.
`[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                                                          
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) `